# Creating a window that can only be dragged within the parent window

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I have a WIN32/C++ app and I want to create child windows in it that cannot be dragged out of the parent window. I want these windows to be owner-drawn, if it matters anyway. Should be simple enough; I'm looking for some basic guidance and tips regarding the subject.

Comment: I started realizing that's what I want when I wrote the question. However, I'm a little rusty with WIN32 and I thought this term is MFC-only. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, Win32 provides MDI functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to make an MDI app. This is much easier using a higher level framework such as MFC, WinForms, VCL etc., but can, of course, be done with plain Win32.

The MSDN documentation can be found here: [Multiple Document Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I can't use these frameworks but I will use Win32 for the task. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called Multiple Document Interface ([MDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface)).